# JavaFX: ChoiceBox with multiple selectable alternatives

Tags: javafx

How to create a `ChoiceBox` in *JavaFX* where **I can select multiple alternatives** (as it was a list of checkboxes)?

Comment: If a `ComboBox` is acceptable instead, you can use a combo box with a cell factory that returns [`CheckBoxListCell`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxListCell.html). Or maybe consider a [`MenuButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html) with `CheckMenuItem`s.

Comment: I think `MenuButton` + `CheckMenuItem`s would be perfect. @James_D do you know any guide where I can learn how to add an arbitrary number of `CheckMenuItem`s having an `ObservableList<String>` ?

Comment: Why not just do `list.stream().map(CheckMenuItem::new).forEach(menuButton.getItems()::add)`?

Comment: That looked like magic to me, but it worked! Thanks @James_D Do you maybe know also an easy way to get a `String[]` array of the selected items?

Comment: You are asking very basic Java questions at this point. Just iterate through the list of menu items, check if they are selected, and if so call `getText()` and put the result in a list.

Comment: Didn't mean to bother :) I just hoped there was a faster "single line solution" as you showed me above. What was the `::` you used there? How can I find more info about it? That could save me a lot of time in the future.

Comment: You can do that in a single line, using the same techniques. `menuButton.getItems().stream().map(CheckMenuItem.class::cast).filter(CheckMenuItem::isSelected).map(CheckMenuItem::getText).collect(Collectors.toList())`. The `::` is just a [Java 8 method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).